# Access properties and methods of <T> from swift generic

Tags: ios, swift, generics, generic-programming

I am not sure if this is possible or not but I *think* I have seen it before.

I am performing some validation on form objects throughout my app and I want a central, reusable way of doing this. I have come up with the following:

```
class RGOValidatedObject<T> {
    var validationPredicate: ((RGOValidatedObject<T>) -> Bool)?

    var isValid: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I want to be able to access the properties and methods of T as if I was subclassing it directly, rather than adding a property to `RGOValidatedObject` to return the value of T. Consider the following:

```
RGOValidatedObject<String>().substringToIndex(1)
```

This is what I mean by access T's properties and methods on the `RGOValidatedObject`, almost as if I just subclassed T.

Is this possible? If so, how do I go about doing so? I am new to the concept of Swift generics but like the look of them.

Comment: What result do you expect from this line `RGOValidatedObject<String>().substringToIndex(1)`?

Comment: I would expect an array index out of range exception, but that's not so much the point. It's more a case of will the compiler recognise that `String` method from `RGOValidatedObject`?

Comment: Looks like you need to add value holder property of type `T` in order. You will receive something very similar to `Optional<T>` enum structure. Probably, knowledge about how `Optional` type implement forwarding can help you with your problem. You may try to research it by digging swift source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no "lifting" syntax that would forward methods this way (though there have been several discussions about similar features in the future). You need to add a `let value: T` property to access it.

A somewhat more common version of this problem is building an `Observable<T>`. You can't make that fully transparent in Swift, such that you could just call `T` methods on it (in the way that you can with KVO magic). It has to be explicit.

Comment: Ah, I feared that might be the case. Thank you for confirming.